# How can I test for exceptions using AndroidTestCase?

Tags: android, junit, android-testing

I'm trying to test for exceptions using AndroidTestCase. I'm trying to use the annotation:

```
@Test(expected=UnsupportedOperationException.class)
```

But the compiler doesn't like that. I thought that this was possible since  AndroidTestCase extends JUnit. Am I missing something? Or do i have to resort to the older try catch idiom to test for exceptions?

Edit:

When I say "the compiler doesn't like that" I mean that android studio cannot resolve the symbol Test or expected.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android JUnit Testing ... How to Expect an Exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5912240/android-junit-testing-how-to-expect-an-exception)

Comment: I looked at that answer and try the annotation they suggest but it doesn't work. Should I ask there instead?

Comment: Well, maybe start with providing more information. What exactly does "doesn't work" mean? Also, can you confirm that you are using Junit4 and that the @Test (no expected exception) annotation behaves as expected?

Comment: By doesn't work I meant that it couldn't find the symbol Test or expected.

Turns out I did not add JUnit to the classpath, after adding it compiles as expected(expected). Not sure why I need to add it though. I thought it was part of AndroidTestCase. Do you know the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I did not add JUnit to the classpath, after adding it compiles as expected(expected). Not sure why I need to add it though. I thought it was part of AndroidTestCase